# Using a 72 ppi image in a 300 ppi print ad

Tags: print-design, resolution

I'm designing an ad  for print in Illustrator. It is set to 300 ppi. I was given a bunch of logos to put in it. One of the logos I have been given is a 72 ppi PNG file. It is much larger than I need it to be in the ad, so I will be scaling it down significantly.

Question: If it is 72 ppi will it print okay in the 300 ppi ad, as it is being scaled down quite a bit?

thanks so much!

Comment: You haven't given enough details, the ppi is irrelevant.  What size is the image in pixels? And what size do you want to print it in inches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Webster's answer is pretty spot on. A reduction of more than 400% *may* make the file okay to use.

In Illustrator, Check the `Resolution` reading in the `Docuemnt Info` Panel once you scale down. (`Window > Document Info`, then use the panel menu to choose `Linked Images` with the image selected)

[image]

That will give you an *Effective PPI* reading based upon scaling. Which may be fine.

A few tips for finding logo when you have been given garbage.

- Check the company's web site. They may have larger raster versions of their logo in use there.
- Check the Company's web site for PDF downloads. You can **often** cannibalize a PDF and extract a *vector* version of their logo from a PDF download they offer.
- Check logo sites such as [BrandsOfTheWorld.com](https://www.brandsoftheworld.com/) -- provided the company is large enough, their logo (in vector form) may be available there.
- Last resort - kick back to the company asking for a better quality version. If they don't have a vector format often asking for the "largest file they have" can work. Often these types of things are sent by sales or managerial staff that have no clue about technical requirements. So, they send you the file they use when posting to Facebook or something. Kicking it back to them may force them to actually *ask* the design staff for an image.

In general a 72ppi image in a commercially printed piece is going to look *horrible* **if** the print production people even *allow* it to go through.

Answer (score 2):

If it is scaled down 416% (300/72) it may appear crisp when printed. BUT I would not accept any bitmapped logos.

That 72 ppi logo may have big fat pixels locked at 72 ppi.

Whenever possible use vector. If your client cannot provide a good logo then you need to acquire it: ask for their printers/publishers contacts, as they will often have good versions of the art, look online for it, recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add, if you extract the logo from the web, always right click > open image in a new tab > read the link. Some developers upload different resolutions for a single file, some use an engine to scale down the image to your screen resolution and some just upload one resolution. Try fiddling around the link, you might find something good. I have even found svg files for home page logo. Sometimes I need to dig into the about us segment to seek for a higher resolution logo.