# Designing a flyer in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

It's my first time to design a flyer in adobe illustrator, but I have a few questions that may sound naive or easy for all of you as experienced designers. I really need your answers as I have to deliver that flyer to the client tomorrow. note that: I already watched all videos on youtube !

1) My document is 4.25 x 5.5 inch, so what should be the bleed?

2) I placed the images in my flyer design, but I can see that those images loss their quality, how can I place them without losing quality, are there additional steps after placing them? and how to make them print- ready with the highest quality as part of the flyer design?

3) How to save the flyer as a PDF for print-ready with all the images and texts added? what are the options that must be changed?

Comment: How many of those videos were cat movies?

Answer (score 3):

> I really need your answers as I have to deliver that flyer to the client tomorrow.

I commend you on venturing out. You might want to consider not taking on clients until you have at least a basic footing in file creation. Remember you don't just represent yourself when you "take on clients". You represent the industry as a whole. And bad word of mouth can reflect on any future designer someone comes across. I'm not stating you won't do a good job. Merely stating that these questions should *really* be knowledge you already have before any "client" is involved. *Especially* an overnight delivery client.

> 1) My document is 4.25 x 5.5 inch, so what should be the bleed?

For US design (assumed since you posted inches, not metric)... .25" or a quarter inch is a decent bleed. It generally encompasses any commercial printer you'll find. Some may ask for .125" (8th inch) some for .25". But there's really no such thing as "too much" bleed - in fact some more complex reproduction methods (gravure, flexo) may require much larger bleeds. So by using .25" you're generally covered for practically all offset printing. I tend to work in picas/points and I use 1p6 Picas or 18pts... which roughly translate to a quarter inch.

> 2) I placed the images in my flyer design, but I can see that those images [lost] their quality, how can I place them without losing quality,

By "place" I assume you are using the `Place` command and inserting *raster* images into an Illustrator document. Raster images are imported *at their set resolution*. That means, if the raster image is only 72ppi, that is what Illustrator imports. Illustrator does *not* increase the native PPI of raster images ever. There are some caveats... such as *effective PPI*. [See Here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/100833/3270) But in general, you need to ensure any raster image is *already* at the correct PPI (300) *before* placing it in Illustrator. And you should be aware that it is practically *never* correct to *enlarge* a raster image within Illustrator. You only degrade the image if you enlarge a raster image.

> 3) How to save the flyer as a PDF for print-ready with all the images and texts added? what are the options that must be changed?

Save as a PDF/X-1a File. Leave everything set at the defaults unless you've *specifically been asked* to change something. That's all you need to to generate a press-ready PDF.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, I have one last question, so If the flyer is a front and a back side. so how can it be saved as one PDF?

Comment: Illustrator artboards are treated as ages in Acrobat. Save as a PDF/X and it'll have a page for every artboard.

Comment: What about the press quality option ? related to @Lucian 's answer. because I am really confused.

Comment: "Press Quality" will save a high resolution file.. so will PDF/X-1a. PDFX is an **ISO standards compliance PDF** that will ensure settings are correct for most offset printing. Lucian's answer is fine, but he's basically telling you to turn on options that are *defaults* for the PDFX formats. In the last 20 years I've saved 3 types of PDFs... 1) Interactive PDFS which are completely inappropriate for printing 2) a "Proof" PDF which has custom settings slightly better than the "Smallest Files size" and 3) A PDF/X-1a file - that's all you really need, except maybe PDF Forms.

Comment: PDF/X info ---> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/X

Comment: Okay, so I will save as a PDF/X-1 and leave the rest as default as I already made the file's bleeds in the new menu, so PDF knows about it by default ? am I right ?

Comment: Yes. Any bleed set in Illustrator will be read/seen/included when saving as a PDF/X file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try 0,125 inches for the bleed. The printer should be able confirm that, or give you a different value when they see your file after step 3 below.
2. Normally no quality is lost when placing files. Quality starts to decrease depending on the export settings you'll be using. Which leads to..
3. When you save a final PDF, choose the 'Press Quality' preset from the PDF export options, and tick the 'All Printer's Marks' and 'Use Document Bleed Settings' options under 'Marks and Bleeds'.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Lucian, You were totally right. The bleed is fine and the image quality was fine when I saved as a PDF press quality.