# Bleed of a flyer designed in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, bleed

I designed a 5.5" x 4 3/16" inch flyer in Illustrator. I set the bleed to 0.125 inch. I finished the flyer and saved it using the PDF/X-1a:2001 preset, left the rest as default. Then delivered it to the client. But he is asking me to create a one-eighth-inch bleed and crop marks. How come? Because I already set the bleed as I said before to 0.125 inch. I also printed a sample of the flyer to check that, and it is printed correctly.

I am really confused, should I save it as a press quality PDF and mark the printer's marks and bleeds or leave it the same?

[image: this is my document with the bleed 0.125 inch]

[image: this is how I saved the flyer I only saved as PDF/X-1a and left the rest as default]

Answer (score 4):

> But he is asking me to create a one-eighth-inch bleed and crop marks.

0.125 inch is indeed 1/8 inch, the PSD/X-1a:2001 PDF preset doesn't include crop marks by default though. Just go to "Marks and Bleeds" and check "Trim Marks". Done.

[image]

Comment: so should i save as @Lucian answer in this link as PDF-PRESS QUALITY if it is better https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/103966/designing-a-flyer-in-illustrator?rq=1

Comment: @minachris either is fine; both will give you a press-ready PDF. Just make sure "Trim Marks" is checked and the bleed is correct